# Can't make check if user already exists in my database

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I started to learn ASP.NET. I create a register system, and when I try to check if the username or email already exists in the database, it's not checked and creates the user even when you have it already.

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    bool exists = false;
    string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM accounts WHERE username='" + username.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", username.Text);

    exists = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() > 0;

    if (exists)
    {
        Response.Write("User already exists");
    }

    string command = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, password) VALUES (@username, @email, @password)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception)
{
    label_msg.Visible = true;
    label_msg.Text = "Something went wrong....";
    throw;
}
finally
{
    Response.Redirect("/layout.aspx");
    conn.Close();
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Why you use cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", username.Text); because you don't have @username parameter in cmd2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check if user Exist already

```
int exists = 0;
string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM accounts WHERE username='" +username.Text + "'";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", username.Text);

exists = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

if (exists>0)
{
    Response.Write("User already exists");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string checkuser = "if exists (select 1 from accounts where username=@username) select 1 else select 0 end";
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);

bool exists = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
```

Having SQL Server check for the existence of matches will stop at the first match instead of potentially returning a set of matches and then it is simply returning a value accordingly. This will minimize data transferred between the server and your software plus avoid performing a count when we really just care if there are any matches.

Comment: Much more efficient on large dataset than **counting** the rows just to determine if at least one exists.....

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to find TRUE/FALSE value or counting the no records always use COUNT(1).

Comment: what are you mean ?
SELECT count(1) FROM accounts ?

Comment: Using `SELECT COUNT(1)` or `SELECT COUNT(*)` is equivalent - there's no benefit in using `COUNT(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
bool exists = false;
string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM accounts WHERE username=@username;";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);

object result = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

if (result != null)
    exists = (Convert.ToInt32(result) == 1) ? true : exists;

if (exists)
{
    Response.Write("User already exists");
}
```

Comment: Good answer for using **parameters** - but using `COUNT(*)` on a large table just to check for existence is less than ideal - after all, you're only interested in knowing if (at least) one entry exists - you don't need to know if there are 717, 18904 or 3 gazillion entries - that just wastes a lot of time. Use `IF EXISTS()` as @RyanGrange showed in his answer